# MSSQL Connection code syntax error?

Tags: php, sql

Below is my connection string for mssql server its named SKPI-APPS1.
I know mssql is to be removed from php but i just need to finish this simple webpage for my company since all of their webpages are made from the old php version so they cannot just easily switch the new php version.

The code below doesn't display anything when I'm trying it with localhost/login.php
doesn't even display errors.

Can anyone define what the problem is coming from?

```
<?php
$myServer = "SKPI-APPS1";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "AFS";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Could you show the error message..

Comment: I do not receive any error message coming from the webpage since it doesn't display anything

Comment: So the page is not displaying any noticeable errors, then you must have sucessfully connected to the database.. Try: `if ($dbhandle){ echo "Successful connection"; }` to verify that there is a sucessful connection to the database. & it's only MySQL_* functions to be removed. MSSQL_* functions are not in the depreciation process

Comment: still doesnt display successful connection sir?

Comment: So it's not showing success, or even issuing a `die("");` what happens when you try to run a query? & have you got error_reporting turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps given below to connect MSSQL with php:

1. Settings related to your php.ini file:

   a) search the variable **mssql.secure_connection** in your **php.ini** file and put it to on mode if its off 
   b) remove comment from the dll extention **php_mssql.dll** (i.e. remove the ; from the front of the extention )
2. Settings related to the dll files. Download a file name **ntwdblib.dll** from the internet. you can download it from **[here](http://www.dlldll.com/getdll/4196.html)** or can search on internet for that. copy the downloaded dll to the apache/bin directory and for IIS copy it to the php extention directory (if path not known can be found in php.ini for variable extension_dir) also you need to have your **php_mssql.dll** in your php extension directory. if its not present please download it and copy it to the default php extension directory.
3. **restart all your services** (i.e. php and apache or iis) and you can use the script given below to connect to your SQL Server.

Credit to http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/how-to-connect-mssql-with-php/

Comment: Hay download first ntwdblib.dll from reference source first. If you want to use php_mssql.dll, that requires 'ntwdblib.dll (bundled)'. Hay, I'm not sir :)

Comment: ntwdblib.dll i will paste it on xamp/apache/bin and xamp/php right?

Comment: im sorry didn't notice that. this connection to mssql is giving me headache

Comment: can we add on gmail and talk on the chat there? please?

Comment: i cant use skype here in my company. only authorized with browsers  i really need this kindly help me please... now im still missing php_mssql.dll

Comment: i already downloaded php_mssql.dll and paste it on the php folder what shall i remove from it? i cant find the ;

Comment: How status. Did you find ntwdblib.dll in php.ini?

Comment: Did you restart apache or IIS?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32301/discussion-between-ivandinglasan-and-thiha)